# C# is adding 00:00:00 unnecessarily

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

My SQL Server is using the DATE datatype, but my C# app is reading this as 'mm/dd/yyyy 00:00:00', can anyone tell me how to get rid of the 0s? (everything else works)...?

```
var sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CustomerOrders.OrderID, Product.ProductName, OrderDetails.QuantityOrdered," +
" Customer.CustomerFirstName, Customer.CustomerLastName, CustomerOrders.OrderDate FROM CustomerOrders" +
" INNER JOIN Product ON CustomerOrders.ProductID = Product.ProductID INNER JOIN Customer on CustomerOrders.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID" +
" INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON CustomerOrders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID;", DatabaseConnection); // uses SQL query to read every piece of data in database
var dataset = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(dataset);
DatabaseConnection.Close();

DatabaseList.Items.Clear();                                           // clears all data in the list
DatabaseList.BeginUpdate();
foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var lvi = new ListViewItem();                                     // rebuilds the list
    lvi.Text = row["OrderID"].ToString();
    lvi.SubItems.Add(row["ProductName"].ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(row["QuantityOrdered"].ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(row["CustomerFirstName"].ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(row["CustomerLastName"].ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(row["OrderDate"].ToString());
    DatabaseList.Items.Add(lvi);
}
DatabaseList.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: use a date time formatting string

Comment: In the .ToString(), you should be able to specify the output format that you want - eg. row["OrderDate"].ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")

Comment: As of .NET 6, you will also have a new struct called `DateOnly` that handles this - it contains just the date - no time portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the time portion of a `DateTime` as `String` you have several options:

```
DateTime orderDate = row.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate");
```

1. 

```
lvi.SubItems.Add(orderDate.ToShortDateString());
```

2. 

```
lvi.SubItems.Add(orderDate.ToString("d"));
```

3. 

```
lvi.SubItems.Add(orderDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Read: [Date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)